# How to bypass youtube's local cache?

Tags: linux, osx, windows, cache, youtube

Youtube performance here in Brazil has been terrible lately.
Checking my browser's activity I can see that my ISP has a local Youtube cache and serves videos in 1.7 MB chunks.
Talking to some friends we verified that at least 2 of the major ISPs in Brazil are doing this.

I know that I could use a proxy to direct my traffic, but I dont want to do it for everything, as it's only Youtube that's been really making me mad.

What could I do to skip that local cache just for Youtube?

I use Mac OS on my personal computer, but have Linux and Windows boxes around the house, a solution for any of them would be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wan't to use only a proxy server for specific sites you should look into [PAC files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config). It is basically a JavaScript file which let's you specify which proxies should be used for which domains. If you have your own network at home you can combine this with [wpad - web proxy autodiscovery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Autodiscovery_Protocol) and Chrome, Firefox, IE and probably Safari. 
This is probably the simplest solution and if your setup is correct you should not have to change anything on your clients, e.g. your dhcp server provides the `DNS Domain Name` and you serve your `pac` file on `http://wpad.domain/wpad.dat` with the mime-type `application/x-ns-proxy-autoconfig`

Another client based solution is to use something like [foxy proxy](http://getfoxyproxy.org/) - an extension to dynamically switch your proxy settings in Firefox, Chrome and IE. While this solution is much simpler than using wpad you'll have to install an extension and change settings in your browsers.

Comment: good call! had completely forgot about those -_- baaaad admin bad admin :P thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One method I've heard of is to use DNS servers (OpenDNS and Google DNS come to mind) outside the country, that way requests will direct to other youtube servers outside the country.

Bear in mind this may adversely affect some things, because your connections may have added network hops between you to what you're trying to reach.

Oh, another option:
You could (as long as youtube servers stay on the same IP address, outside the country) add an entry in your hosts file to redirect just youtube servers outside the country.  But if the servers get moved, that could complicate things.

Comment: I already use google's dns servers :/
As for putting entries on hosts files would be kinda impossible given the multitude of IPs/Servers youtube uses.